# A variable I believe to be initialized sends an error of not being initialized

Tags: java

I am trying to compare to String arrays and have a return value of either true or false on whether the Strings are equal or not. I initialized finalAnswer at the top, but when I try to return the value, it brings up an error of not being initialized.

```
public static boolean equals(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
    boolean finalAnswer;
    if (array1.length == array2.length) {
        finalAnswer = false;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i > array1.length; i++) {
            if (array1[i] == array2[i]) {
                finalAnswer = true;
            }
            else {
                finalAnswer = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return finalAnswer;
}
```

Comment: your second line is `boolean finalAnswer;`. if you read it right you see its not initialized. initializing looks like this: `boolean finalAnswer = false;`

Answer (score 1):

Your logic has many errors, and can be simplified by eliminating the variable causing your compilation error :

```
public static boolean equals(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
    if (array1.length != array2.length) {
        return false; // you should return false if the lengths are NOT equal
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) { // was >
            if (!array1[i].equals(array2[i])) { // don't compare Strings with ==
                return false; // return immediately if the Strings don't match
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Simple solution, but I am not a very big fan of inline returns.  Instead let the variable flow through the logic and return itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing local variables with member variables of a class (also called fields). As you have declared `finalAnswer` inside a methode, it's a local variable and does not get initialized by simply declaring the variable as of type boolean in `boolean finalAnswer;`. If you would have declared it as a member variable it would get initialized with its default value (which is `false` in the case of a boolean variable) when you create an object of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your variable explicitly like this:
`boolean finalAnswer = false;`

A few other notes:

- `array1[i] == array2[i]` -> strings should be compared using `equals()` unless you want to test reference equality
- `i > array1.length` this is always false

---

It can be greatly simplified to:

```
public static boolean equals(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
    return Arrays.equals(array1, array2);
}
```

You can have a look at the implementation of the `Arrays.equals()` for the inspiration.